# Show Outline of Code

Tags: navigation

Is there a way, built-in or with a plugin, to get an outline of my code in Vim?

In Eclipse, there is a panel that shows an outline of the code in the file, showing a breakdown of the classes and methods:

```
MyClass
  MyClass()
  myMethod(int, String)
AnotherClass
  someMoreMethod()
```

Anything is possible in Vim, but is there currently a way to do this, either built-in or by installing a plugin?

Support for jumping to the different methods would be nice, but all I need is something to show the structure of the code.  I would prefer a solution that worked for most of the top languages, but I really need Perl support (and yes, I know my sample code is Java).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is possible with [Tagbar plugin](https://github.com/majutsushi/tagbar), which use ctags to generate the tags. Used in collaboration with [Universal Ctags](https://ctags.io/), it supports various langages.

Answer (score 1):

In the interests of completeness, this can also be done with the [Taglist plugin](http://vim-taglist.sourceforge.net/). Most of the advice you will find on the internet recommends the newer Tagbar over Taglist, but reports of the latter's demise seem to have been exaggerated — it was updated as recently as 2013 — and it remains the top-rated and most downloaded plugin on [the official Vim site's script pages](https://vim.sourceforge.io/scripts/script_search_results.php?order_by=rating).

One possible advantage is that Taglist allows the display of tags from multiple files, whereas Tagbar always displays the tags from the current file. I switched to Tagbar several years ago, though, so I'm afraid I can't give a detailed rundown of the differences.